# Bootstrap icon-phone not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

the icon-phone in the div is not showing, but anothers icons is showed like icon-map-marker and icon-enveloppe.

Here is my part of code :

```
<div class="right-side hidden init">
    <div class="info-label">
          <i class="icon-phone"></i>
          <span>myphone </span>
    </div>

    <div class="info-label">
          <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
          <span>France</span>
    </div>

    <div class="info-label">
          <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
          <span>myemail</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap version 2.3.1

Comment: check all icons provided by Bootstrap. You can also check font-awesome for more icon options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`icon-phone` isn't a default icon in Bootstrap 2.3.1

see: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.1/base-css.html#icons for all available icons

Comment: Thank's, i must use another version